# How can I use my own diff tool with `add --patch` and the like?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-diff, git-add, git-patch

I use an offbeat diff tool called [diffr](https://github.com/mookid/diffr), like this:

```
diffr="diffr \
      --colors removed:background:00:foreground:01 \
      --colors refine-removed:background:0:foreground:124 \
      --colors added:background:0:foreground:10 \
      --colors refine-added:background:0:foreground:35:intense \
      | less -R"

git config --global pager.diff "$diffr"
git config --global pager.show "$diffr"
git config --global pager.log "$diffr"
```

My normal workflow also commonly makes use of the `--patch` and `--interactive` flags when adding and checking out code.

However, the `--patch` switch appears to use the default (colordiff?) and not diffr.

How can I coerce diffr as the diff tool in this context (and any others I may not be thinking of)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes all you have to do to find the answer is ask the question.

The solution is:

```
git config --global interactive.diffFilter "$diffr"
```

Comment: An explanation would however be welcome, or at least just a link to the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-interactivediffFilter).